# chrome and firefox browsers not sending kerbros token in WWW-Authenticate header to Negotiate

Tags: c++, windows, firefox, spnego, sspi

I am working on SPNEGO authentication using windows SSPI, is there a way to change browser settings to send kerbros token ?

I tried changing firefox settings in about:config to add trusted uri but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

You did not enable it on Firefox. Chrome works as IE, using registry settings. Set `network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris` and maybe `network.negotiate-auth.delegation-uris` in Firefox and you are done.

Comment: I tried changing the settings and I still got NTLM tokens.

While working on NTLM tokens, when I send clients NTLM response to AcceptSecurtyContext(), I got invalid token as status. Any inputs on this ? Server and Client are on the same domain.

Comment: Talk to your admin and check your setup. It must be the case. Use Wireshark and analyze the Kerberos errors.